# Set OS env var via python

Tags: python

Is there a way within Python to set an OS environment var that lives after the Python script has ended?.. So if I assign a var within the Python script and the script ends I want it to be available once I run a "printenv" via terminal. I've tried using the sh library using os.system but once the program finishes that var is not available via "printenv".

Comment: no you can't, no process can... You have to set your variables from python, then run the subsequent shells in the same process.

Comment: For linux OS, write the variable into `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal those only apply when a new shell is spawned. For .bashrc, it won't be sourced unless it's an interactive shell.

Comment: Look at how programs like `ssh-agent` work: They emit shell scripts on their stdout; if the user wants to import those variables into their shell, they need to do something like `eval "$(ssh-agent)"`.

Comment: You can modify the files/registries where the OS picks the environment variables from, but those would not apply to the current environment (shell), only to the newly started ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what `ssh-agent`, `gpg-agent` and similar tools do: Emit a shell script on your stdout, and document that the user should `eval` your program's output to activate the variables set by that script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex, pipes, sys

# pipes.quote on Python 2, shlex.quote on Python 3
quote = shlex.quote if hasattr(shlex, 'quote') else pipes.quote

# Detect when user **isn't** redirecting our output, and emit a warning to stderr
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    sys.stderr.write("WARNING: This program's output should be used as follows:\n")
    sys.stderr.write('           eval "$(yourprog)"\n')
    sys.stderr.write("         Otherwise environment variables will not be honored.\n")

new_vars={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux'}
for (k, v) in new_vars.items():
    sys.stdout.write('%s=%s; ' % (quote(k), quote(v)))
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Use of `quote()` ensures that even a value like `foo=$(run-something)` is assigned as a literal value, rather than invoking `run-something` as a command.

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to explore the above and seems to give me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Child processes inherit environment of parent processes by default, but the opposite is not possible.

Indeed, after the child process has started, the memory of all other processes is protected from it (segregation of context execution). This means it cannot modify the state (memory) of another process.

At best it can send IPC signals...

*More technical note: you need to debug a process (such as with `gdb`) in order to control its internal state. Debuggers use special kernel APIs to read and write memory or control execution of other processes.*